# How can I manually calculate the Bonferroni correction?

Tags: r, p-value, bonferroni

I created a statistical model with one categorical factor with six levels and performed a posthoc test to obtain the significance level for every contrast (15 comparisons). I wonder if I should apply the Bonferroni correction to account for multiple comparisons.

Say that I have a vector named "p.values" with the 15 p-values obtained from the posthoc test:

```
0.9724 
0.0013 
0.1997 
0.9775 
0.1358 
0.0001 
0.0343 
1.0000 
0.0205 
0.4386 
0.0001
0.5586 
0.0422 
1.0000 
0.0259
```

Would it be correct to calculate the adjusted p-values as follows:

```
adj.p <- p.values/15 #(the number of comparisons)

bon.p.values <- round(1-(1-adj.p)^15,4)
```

Obtaining the following values:

```
0.6341 
0.0013 
0.1821 
0.6361 
0.1275 
0.0001 
0.0338 
0.6447 
0.0203 
0.3593 
0.0001
0.4341 
0.0414 
0.6447 
0.0256
```

Are these new p-values Bonferroni corrected?

Comment: I don‘t think so. Have you checked what Bonferroni correction does? What you typically do is to take your desired alpha level (e.g. 0.05) and divide it by the number of hypotheses (here 15). This then. Is the alpha level against which you compare your original p values to see if they are significant. Note, though, that there are better corrections than Bonferroni.

Comment: no you multiply by 15 not divide `pmin(1, p * length(p)); p.adjust(p, method = 'bonferroni')`

Comment: Thank you both!

Answer (score 5):

No, unfortunately your correction formula is wrong.

The [Bonferroni correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction) compares a test statistic's $p$ value out of $m$ hypotheses to a nominal $\alpha$ by checking whether
$$ p<\frac{\alpha}{m}. $$
Of course, you can alternatively modify the $p$ values rather than $\alpha$ and check whether
$$ mp<\alpha $$
(yes, the term on the left can be greater than one).

The Bonferroni correction is notoriously conservative. You may want to consider [more powerful (but also more complicated) methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-wise_error_rate#Controlling_procedures) like Holm's stepwise or Šidák's procedure.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Stephan.